# Mosh: Retain backscroll beyond terminal window height

Tags: ssh, terminal, mosh

I'm experimenting using Mosh instead of raw SSH for remote shell connections. So far I like it, but I've become used to being able to page-up or scroll through backscroll in my terminal window to see the results of older commands or commands that print too much info to fit in a single window. This works fine with normal SSH connections, but Mosh seems to be "eating" lines beyond the height of the window, so when I scroll back all I can see is stuff printed before I invoked Mosh. Is there a way I can get Mosh to behave like raw SSH and retain the backscroll?

If it matters, the client is running on OS X Mountain Lion (10.7) in the standard "Terminal" program, with tcsh.

Comment: [This answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/161906/33055) on this site refers to [this](https://filippo.io/my-remote-shell-session-setup/) OSX specific solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/keithw/mosh/issues/122) from the author of Mosh, Keith Winstein, the workaround is to use `screen` or `tmux` to have the ability to scroll back.

Comment: Okay, thanks. That's a bit frustrating; tmux and screen do too much. Mosh appealed because it was merely SSH but better.

Comment: I'm hoping for native scrolling support too. Mosh is still really new, so we'll see where it goes.

Comment: I tried both `screen` and `tmux` on the server, but none worked. Instructions will be very helpful?

Comment: Yes, scrolling support would be nice.